# HEROKU AND Ruby on rails: Problems database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to ruby development and I had a problem with the database when deploying the project on heroku

I used postgresql as a database. Test created an entry in the database using the name:string field. Then I made a migration and decided to check the performance locally.

```
<h1><%= @name.name %></h1>
```

Locally the database works correctly.
But when deploying this project on heroku, it gives the following picture.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObBAN.png)

Logs:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u90ws.png)

Database on heroku after migration
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PHnl.png)

Comment: Run `heroku logs -t` in your console and see what's the error

Answer (score 1):

From your log screenshot, I could see that the error is `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find User with id=2)`.

I am sure you're loading with something like `User.find(2)` in `WelcomeController#show`.

Just make sure `User#2` exists or loading other existing User.
If it doesn't solve your issue, please let me know.
Good luck with your journey in learning Rails.

Answer (score 0):

Like said above, the problem is that your record does not exist in production. If you added it locally, it's normal that is has not been added when pushed to Heroku, as the Database is reset.

There are many ways to fix your problem, here are two:

You can use the seed file in the folder `db/seeds`, in which you added your `User.create!(id: 2)` and run:

```
heroku run rails db:seed -a name_of_your_app
```

Or you can run a rails console from which you `User.create!(id: 2)` from Heroku to manually create that missing user:

```
heroku run rails c -a name_of_your_app
```

You should also learn how to read errors that get printed in the console, `Record Not Found` could have happened locally and has not much to do with Heroku. You should be able to tell what the problem is rather quickly if you learn to do so.

Comment: Everything worked if prescribed heroku pg:reset and heroku pg:push. But as a rule, migrate the local database to heroku